# float images into 2 columns without explicitly defining columns in html

Tags: php, css

I have a php script that queries a database for images, and then outputs the images onto the screen with a foreach loop.  All the images have the same width, but different heights.  I want to display these images in 2 columns. The foreach loop means that I can't explicitly define two columns in the html and place the images into the column. As I have it now on the site, each image is floated left, but this creates awkward vertical spaces between images of different heights.

Not sure if I'm explaining this well, [so here's a jsfiddle that shows what I have now and what I want it to look like.](http://jsfiddle.net/R8jBb/) In here I have coded each item so that it look right, but when it's live I wont know each images height or be able to change it.

If there is a way to put two columns directly in the html, it needs to output the images like so, which is counterintuitive for a loop in columns:

1 2

3 4

not

1 3

2 4

Ideally I wont need to use some odd php or javascript workaround, but instead will be able to just edit the css for the image boxes

```
.img_box {
  float: left;
  width: $img-width;
  max-height: 600px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.rate_img {
  width:$img-width;
}
```

php after pulling image info from database

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo '
     <div class="img_box">
        <a href="' . $row['file_loc'] . '"rel="lightbox[main]" title="' . $row['name'] . '" >
            <img src="' . $row['file_loc'] . '" class="rate_img" />
        </a>
     </div>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's impossible to get the effect that you want in just html and css.

To fill up the available white-space you would need to use something like javascript, take a look for example at the [jQuery Masonry plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/) (there are probably jQuery-less options as well...).